# Angular 4 Bootstrap 4 not rendering properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I have a fresh created Angular 4 CLI app with the following packages installed:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta jquery tether popper.js --save
```

.angular-cli.json extraction:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
  "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

],
```

With this setup I have a navbar component with the html code from [the official Bootstrap 4 page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) which is not rendering properly:
[image]
It has a toggle button even when a browser is in full screen mode, background color is missing, "Navbar" and toggler are swapped.

However, it works perfectly when I use [Bootstrap 4 CDN](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/). Any other styles except for the navbar work as expected in both cases.

So, what am I doing wrong when working with Bootstrap installed locally?

Comment: Did you looked bootstrap 4 navbar API, it has been changed drastically.

Comment: You're using Bootrap 4 beta but linking the alpha docs.

Comment: @hdk Thanks, you're right! How could I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds there is a breaking change with css in 4.0.0-**Beta**.

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/812

Just downgrade your bootstrap version as well:

> npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save

Note: the CDN you tried is using **apha.6** that why it was working :)

Answer (score 4):

It happens due to bootstrap version incompatibility, to get around, in styles.css, add this line:

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this config in **angular.json**. Notice how we use node_modules/popper.js/dist/**umd**/popper.min.js. This seems to work.

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

All the best !